# Usando resultado de coluna para compor outra

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Olá, resolvendo um [problema](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2988) do beecrownd sobre sql tentei usar a 'coluna ao lado' como variável para compor o resultado da última coluna.

```
SELECT 
    q1.name,
    COUNT(q1.games) as matches,
    COUNT(q1.games = '+' OR NULL) as victories,
    COUNT(q1.games = '-' OR NULL) as defeats,
    COUNT(q1.games = '=' OR NULL) as draws,
    (victories * 3 + draws) as score -- Isso não funciona, mas é o que expressa minha intenção no código.
    FROM 
...
```

O que certamente me retornou o erro: 'ERROR:  column "victories" does not exist'.

Gostaria de saber se é possível usar as colunas 'ao lado' como variáveis para compor o resultado de uma última coluna. Já que, caso contrário terei que deixar o código mais verboso para resolver o problema.

Código que funciona:

```
SELECT 
    q1.name,
    COUNT(q1.games) as matches,
    COUNT(q1.games = '+' OR NULL) as victories,
    COUNT(q1.games = '-' OR NULL) as defeats,
    COUNT(q1.games = '=' OR NULL) as draws,
    (COUNT(q1.games = '+' OR NULL) * 3 + COUNT(q1.games = '=' OR NULL)) as score
    FROM 
...
```

Comment: não é possível usar como no primeiro exemplo, mas se "isolar" numa subquery sim, algo assim; `select (victories * 3 + draws) as score from (SELECT 
    q1.name,
    COUNT(q1.games) as matches,
    COUNT(q1.games = '+' OR NULL) as victories,
    COUNT(q1.games = '-' OR NULL) as defeats,
    COUNT(q1.games = '=' OR NULL) as draws from ....)`

Comment: Compreendo, obrigado.